# Multiple input feeds to netcat

Tags: python, unix, netcat

This is related to passing input through stdin to a binary running on a port. I am able to run the binary using netcat as follows:

```
nc $server $port
```

Now to pass a single line, I can get the following working:

```
python -c 'print "AAAA"' | nc $server $port
```

However, I am not able to figure out a way to write to stdin twice.

My program has a flow something like below:

The first feed depends on some response from the server.

```
line 5: read(stdin,&buffer,20); // This entry is based on some question from the server and need to be determined dynamically
```

The second feed needs to passed as a python output as it needs to contain hex characters as well.

```
line 8: read(stdin,&buffer2,20); // This feed is static.
```

Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand the problem, but you can run multiple commands in a subshell and pipe the output of all of them to another process:

```
$ (python -c 'print "AAAA"'; python -c 'print "BBBB"') | nc $server $port
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @nickgrim. However, my program flow contains two read functions sequentially. The first feed needs to be dynamically determined i.e it requires user interaction. The second can passed as a hardcoded string. I have edited my question again. Hope it is clear now.